# Why arent the inputs following the patterns?

Tags: c#, regex, exception, get, trim

I'm making a Windows Forms app to request contact information. I created a class to trim the input text and check if the `TextBox` is empty. I also assigned patterns for the `email` and `phonenumber`. However, none of these seem to be working when I run the application.

### Form

```
string quantity = string.Empty;
string name = string.Empty;
string emailpattern = string.Empty;
string phonepattern = string.Empty;

const int ContactWindow = 90;
const int SuggestedContactOffset = 3;

#region Constructors

public frmRequestContact()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

#endregion


#region Event Handlers

private void frmRequestContact_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //initialize contact date control
    dtpContactDate.MaxDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(ContactWindow);
    dtpContactDate.MinDate = DateTime.Today;
    dtpContactDate.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(SuggestedContactOffset);

    //initialize contact method control
    rbEmail.Checked = true;
}   

private void btnContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Input variables
    string quantity = string.Empty;
    string name = string.Empty;
    string emailpattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,}$";
    string phonepattern = @"^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$";

    // Contact Date
    DateTime contactDate = DateTime.MinValue;

    // Contact Method
    ContactMethod method = ContactMethod.Unassigned;

    // Gather inputs
    if (GetContactDate(ref contactDate) 
        && GetContactMethod(ref method) 
        && GetEmail(ref emailpattern) 
        && GetName(ref name) 
        && GetQuantity(ref quantity) 
        && GetPhone(ref phonepattern))
    {
        // Submit contact request and close the form
        string format = "Your contact request has been entered.\n\n" 
            + "Quantity: {0}\n" 
            + "Name: {1}\n" 
            + "Email: {2}\n" 
            + "Phone: {3}\n" 
            + "Contact Date: {4:D}\n" 
            + "Contact Method: {5}\n";

        string msg = string.Format(format, quantity, name, emailpattern, phonepattern, contactDate, method);
        MessageBox.Show(msg, Application.ProductName);

        Close();
    }
}

private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    Input.TrimText(tb.Text);
}

#endregion


#region Input

private bool GetQuantity(ref string quantity)
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        Input.TrimText(txtQuantity.Text);
        if (Input.IsTextEmpty(txtQuantity.Text))
            throw new InputRequiredException();
        quantity = txtQuantity.Text;

        return success;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        string remediation = "Enter quantity.";
        Input.ShowError(error, remediation);
        Input.SelectText(txtQuantity);
    }
    return success;
}

private bool GetName(ref string name)
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        Input.TrimText(txtName.Text);//removing whitespace
        if (Input.IsTextEmpty(txtName.Text))//checking if the input is empty, if so throw new exception
            throw new InputRequiredException();
        name = txtName.Text;
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        string remediation = "Enter name of individual to contact.";
        Input.ShowError(error, remediation);
        Input.SelectText(txtName);
    }
    return success;
}

private bool GetEmail(ref string emailpattern)
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        Input.TrimText(txtEmail.Text); //removing whitespace
        if (Input.IsTextEmpty(txtEmail.Text))
            throw new InputRequiredException();
        emailpattern = txtEmail.Text;
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        string remediation = "Enter a valid email.";
        Input.ShowError(error, remediation);
        Input.SelectText(txtEmail);
    }
    return success;
}

bool GetPhone(ref string phonepattern)
{
    bool success = true;
    try
    {
        Input.TrimText(txtPhone.Text);
        if (Input.IsTextEmpty(txtPhone.Text))
            throw new InputRequiredException();
        phonepattern = txtPhone.Text;
        success = true;
    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        string remediation = "Enter a valid phone number.";
        Input.ShowError(error, remediation);
        Input.SelectText(txtPhone);
    }
    try
    {
        int Phone = Convert.ToInt32(txtPhone.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        string remediation = "Enter a valid phone number.";
        Input.ShowError(error, remediation);
        Input.SelectText(txtPhone);

    }
        return success;
}

bool GetContactDate(ref DateTime contactDate)
{
    contactDate = dtpContactDate.Value;
    return true;
}

bool GetContactMethod(ref ContactMethod method)
{
    //find selected option
    if (rbEmail.Checked)
        method = ContactMethod.Email;
    else if (rbPhone.Checked)
        method = ContactMethod.Phone;
    else if (rbEither.Checked)
        method = ContactMethod.Either;
    else //no option selected!
    {
        Showerror("Select a contact method");
        return true;
    }

    return true;
}

void Showerror(string msg)
{
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Request Contact", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

#endregion
```

### Inputs

```
class Input
{
    static public string TrimText(string A)
    {
        return A.Trim();
    }

    internal static bool IsTextEmpty(string A)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(A))
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    internal static void ShowError(object error, string remediation)
    {           
    }

    static public void SelectText(TextBox textBox1)
    {
         textBox1.SelectAll();
    }
}
```

There are no errors showing in the code and the program runs smoothly but I am not getting the desired output. I am an utter noob when it comes to coding and understand the code might have logical errors. Whether there is one mistake or multiple or if the code is simply unfinished please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Is there a way you can produce a _minimal_ example and clarify your specific question? The entirety of the code is nice, but it will be quicker for everyone if you can narrow in on a specific problem/section of code.

Comment: @Chris the confusing thing about this code is that I dont know where the error is because there arent any. If I had to pick one tho I would pick this.

Comment: private bool GetEmail(ref string emailpattern)
    {
        bool success = true;
        try
        {
            Input.TrimText(txtEmail.Text); //removing whitespace
            if (Input.IsTextEmpty(txtEmail.Text))
                throw new InputRequiredException();
            emailpattern = txtEmail.Text;
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            string remediation = "Enter a valid email.";
            Input.ShowError(error, remediation);
            Input.SelectText(txtEmail);
        }
        return success;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't write the trimmed text back into the `TextBox`

```
private void TextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    // Input.TrimText(tb.Text); // <-- your code
    tb .Text = Input.TrimText(tb.Text);
}
```

About the `emailpattern`. At the moment you just assign the value of `txtEmail.Text` to it and than display it in a `MessageBox`. In the following code i removed erverything and just left the parts where you do something with `emailpattern`.

```
private void btnContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Input variables   
    string emailpattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+.[A-Z]{2,}$";    

    if (GetEmail(ref emailpattern))
    {        
        string msg = string.Format(format, quantity, name, emailpattern, phonepattern, contactDate, method);
        MessageBox.Show(msg, Application.ProductName);
        Close();
    }
}

private bool GetEmail(ref string emailpattern)
{  
    emailpattern = txtEmail.Text;
    success = true;    
    return success;
}
```

Comment: same result @mardukar

Comment: Every time you used `Input.TrimText(...)` you didn't write it back into the source. Have you corrected them all?

Comment: thanks. I just did. That fixes the trimtext issue. however its still not checking the patterns or catching the exceptions.

Comment: I have extended my answer @XaviorHansa